# How can I loop through a bunch of web pages and save all data to a single CSV file?

Tags: r

How can I loop through a bunch of web pages and save all data to a single CSV file?  Or, loop through a bunch of web pages and save data from one web page to one CSV file?

Here’s a sample of the URL.
http://www.hockey-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=1&day=1&year=2014
Here’s another.
http://www.hockey-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=1&day=30&year=2014

```
library(XML)
NHL <- htmlParse("http://www.hockey-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=1&day=1&year=2014")
class(NHL)
NHL.tables <- readHTMLTable(NHL,stringAsFactors = FALSE)
length(NHL.tables)
write.csv(NHL.tables, file = "NHLData.csv")
```

How can I set start and end dates and loop through all pages between those dates?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
library(magrittr)

start_date = mdy("January 1, 2014") %>% as.Date
end_date = mdy("January 30, 2014") %>% as.Date

catalog = 
  data_frame(date = start_date:end_date %>% as.Date) %>%
  mutate(month = 
           date %>% format("%m") %>% as.numeric,
         day = 
           date %>% format("%d") %>% as.numeric,
         year =
           date %>% format("%Y") %>% as.numeric,
         URL = 
           "http://www.hockey-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=%s&day=%s&year=%s" %>%
           sprintf(month, day, year) ) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  do(tables = 
       .$URL %>%
       htmlParse %>%
       readHTMLTable(stringAsFactors = FALSE) )

skaters = 
  catalog %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  do(.$tables %>%
       extract2(1) %>%
       use_series(skaters) )

goalies = 
  catalog %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  do(.$tables %>%
       extract2(1) %>%
       use_series(goalies) )
```

Edit:

```
setwd("C:/insert_path_to_your_data")

skaters %>% write.csv("skaters.csv", row.names = FALSE)
goalies %>% write.csv("goalies.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks.  This looks pretty sweet!!  I love the timer!!  By the way, where does the data go?  I checked the default working directory and didn't find anything there.

Comment: skaters and goalies should have the final datasets. The original data are stored in the tables list contained in catalog.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to write out the tables in the end. See edit for output.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this place.  I don't totally know what you mean.  Can you please give me the full code so I can copy/paste it, and run it, and learn from it?  Thanks!!

Comment: Run the code after edit (above), which allows you to choose what directory you want to save your data in.